# How to name a subexpression in cypher for readability and reuse?

Tags: neo4j, refactoring, cypher

For example, let’s say many of my queries use the idea of being a cousin. They might describe “**b** is a cousin of **a**” with

```
(a)-[:PARENT]->()-[:PARENT]->(grandparent)<-[:PARENT]-()<-[:PARENT]-(b)
```

Is there any way to give that chunk of logic a name, so I can do something more like:

```
(a)-[:COUSIN]-(b)
```

Then it would be clearer when reading other queries that they're using the same structure, and I'd only have one place to fix it when I find out that definition of "cousin" has a bug.

Comment: You can't make this for now. But, you can really create the cousin relationship into your graph.

Comment: You say "for now." Is there work underway in this direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is an implicit relationship. A relationship exists between cousins, it just isn't explicitly modeled in the graph. So one thing you could do is create a relationship between all cousins in the graphs and then use the `COUSIN` relationship directly.

Comment: Bummer. Having to make explicit versions of implicit relationships is a big thing I was hoping to **avoid** when switching away from SQL, as one of our primary complaints is a cache layer that gets out-of-sync or slow-to-update when the inputs change.